# Localhost redirected you too many times NextJs 13 and JWT verify middleware

Tags: authentication, next.js, jwt, next.js13, app-router

Everything works perfectly fine one problem is that when I am logged In I am redirected to "/" page and if a user wanna go to "/login" or "/register" page even after being logged In they should be redirected to "/" page how can I add that feature in this code right now I am able get to "/login" page even after logged in but the page says localhost redirected you too many times error in the web page.

The code middleware.js :

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { verify } from "jsonwebtoken";

export function middleware(request) {
  const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
  const jwt = request.cookies.get("jwt")?.value;
  const path = request.nextUrl.pathname;

  if (!jwt && !["/login", "/register"].includes(path)) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", request.url));
  } else if (jwt && (path === "/login" || path === "/register")) {
    try {
      verify(jwt, secret);
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", request.url));
    } catch (error) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", request.url));
    }
  }
  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/dashboard/:path*", "/login", "/register", "/"],
};
```

I was trying successful login and register using JWT verify and NextJs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `verify(jwt, secret)` is failing. it is throwing error. so you are running into `catch` block. In the catch block you are redirected to the "login` again. So, you are hitting

```
else if (jwt && (path === "/login" || path === "/register"))
```

because `jwt` is valid and `path==="/login"`. since `verify` is throwing error, you are hitting the catch block so you are kinda in a loop

Comment: Then how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: do u confirm that `verify()` is throwing error. try to `console.log(error)` inside catch block.

Comment: Yeah I got this error in terminal :                                                            
 ``` [JsonWebTokenError: secret or public key must be provided] {
  name: 'JsonWebTokenError',
  message: 'secret or public key must be provided'
}```

Comment: that means `process.env.JWT_SECRET` is undefined. `console.log(secret)`. did you set environment variable correctly.

Comment: Yeah you are right I am getting nothing and I have stored it in .env like this JWT_SECRET="secret123"
NODE_ENV=development   and I am able to access process.env.NODE_ENV but not able to get JWT_SECRET don't know why ?

Comment: `JWT_SECRET=secret123` with out ""

Comment: Thanks man the problem was I just  started using NextJS 13 and we have to declare .env inside the nextconfig file but instead I defined it  in .env thanks again.

Comment: you are not done yet :) what if `verify` fails in the future for any other reason. you have to think about how to handle the `catch` block

Comment: may be I will delete jwt cookie if verify failed and If got error, what would you suggest

Comment: invalidation the jwt is a good idea. but in real world applications, if the token verification fails, that is a big security issue, so you should somehow inform the user.  this is just edge case.